# Use of relativesource findancestor in datavisualization chart lineseries

Tags: c#, wpf, relativesource

I've generated a Datavisualization Line chart, now I'm trying to build a custom tooltip and am close, but not quite there yet.  Here's my pertinent XAML for the View (using MVVM).

```
<charting:Chart x:Name="Chart1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Title="Profit and Loss"  
            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
            PlotAreaStyle="{StaticResource PlotAreaStyle}" 
            MinHeight="200" 
            MinWidth="200" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <charting:Chart.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="LineDataPointTemplate" TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
            <Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="1">
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentControl>
                            <ContentControl.Content>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiFormattingConverter}">
                                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                        <Binding  Path="Title" >
                                            <Binding.RelativeSource>
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                                            </Binding.RelativeSource>
                                        </Binding>
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </ContentControl.Content>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </charting:Chart.Resources>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="ChartLoadedMethod" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <charting:Chart.Series>
      <charting:LineSeries x:Name="entrySeries" ItemsSource="{Binding EntryDataPointColl}" 
             Title="{Binding entryDateLegend}"
             d:DataContext="EntryDataPointColl.xml"
             IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Xvalue}" 
             FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
             DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Yvalue}" 
             >
        <charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type charting:LineDataPoint}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource LineDataPointTemplate}"/>
```

Well, I don't know how to input code...I indented 4 spaces, then did a paste, but that doesn't seem to have worked.

In any event, I want to use relative source to refer to either the `LineSeries` or the `Chart` itself so that in my `MultiFormattingConverter`, I'll have access to the `DataContext` (my vm) and the collections.  Then I can use data from the "point" which is what the `TemplatedParent` gives me to look up values for all 3 of my `LineSeries` and product a tooltip which has values for each observable collection.  No matter what I specify in the `FindAncestor, AncestorType=` code, I still end up with "unset" as the first object in the value array.

The code above is using one variation by specifying my `UserControl`, but it doesn't work.  I've tried `charting:Chart`, `charting:Chart1`, `charting:LineSeries`, `charting:entrySeries` but nothing seems to work for me.  Can someone help me figure out what to specify in the `FindAncestor`?

Comment: Yeah, the text area they use here reacts weirdly to tabs instead of spaces - I always paste whatever I plan on writing into Notepad++ and do a Tab->space conversion first...

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `ToolTip` structure is not a child of the `Chart` visual tree, so there is no way for it to walk up/down the tree and find what you are looking for - in fact, if you were to look at this with Snoop or some other WPF sniffing tool, you'd see that the `ToolTip` tree effectively "ends" right at your `StackPanel` (or very close to it)

Try using `ElementName` bindings instead of `FindAncestor`, and specify the name of your chart/series elements. That can sometimes be used to work around this type of issue.

An alternative approach is to create a sort of "shim" that can proxy back to the `Chart` from inside that tool tip, but that's a bit outside of my willingness to type into my phone at the moment. :)

Comment: Well, I wonder...because what I did was use Mole2010 once inside my MultiFormattingConverter code wherein I did a VisualTreeHelper.GetParent on value[1] (which is the tooltip) and the parent is the Canvas - in this case the PolyLine.  And, the PolyLine (canvas) has as it's datacontext, my viewmodel: ModelOptionChainViewModel. So, at this point I can forget about all this relative source stuff and simply use the TemplatedParent (the LineDataPoint) use the GetParent (the Canvas or PolyLine) and the extract the datacontext within which are my 3 observable collections...

Comment: Correction, the TemplatedParent is the LineDataPoint, not the Tooltip as I had previously posted...sorry.

Comment: @JohnBlacker Uhh...so are you saying you misposted the original question, or that you've changed the structure of your XAML such that you no longer need to do the binding in the `ToolTip`?

Comment: Neither, I misposted my comment above wherein I said that value[1] was the tooltip; rather, value[1] in the above xaml is the LineDataPoint.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try the ElementName approach suggested above.  Rather, I decided to simplify by using a regular FormattingConverter with the value passed being the TemplatedParent - the LineDataPoint.  Now I use the GetParent(ldp) and I have the Canvas, which has my vm as it's datacontext.  At this point I have access to my observable collections and can extract the values I want to include in my custom tooltip.
Thanks to all posters.